# Functors vs Function Closures in Python

Tags: python, function, closures, functor, functools

We were supposed to use functors for our lab, and then use function closures instead. 
For the functors we imported partial as command from functools, where the set up ended up looking something like:

```
digit = command(self.add_character, text = number)

label.bind('< Button-1 >', digit)
```

where we would then bind a method developed later on to a label...
How would I do something like this with function closures and not functors?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a lambda to bind an anonymous function:

```
label.bind('< Button-1 >', lambda ev: self.add_character(ev, text=number))
```

Here, I'm assuming that label callbacks usually are passed in an event argument. You may need to adjust the number of arguments that the callback is passed. It this is a `tkinter`-based GUI, just the event is going to be passed in.

The `number` value is closed over, while when using a `functools.partial()` object, the `number` value would be bound as an argument to the callable.